# Missing System.Collection dependency for Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection when using mono

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono

I am working with a rather complex project that has a lot of dependencies. On my Debian 9 installation with an old Mono (4.8 from Xamarin, sadly an upgrade is not possible at the time) when I try to run the executable of my application I get the following error (I have excluded logs that are not relevant to the issue):

```
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/home/test/Application/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll'.
Mono: Image addref Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions[0xa3d4aa0] -> /home/test/Application/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll[0xa3d3ea0]: 2
Mono: Prepared to set up assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions' (/home/test/Application/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll)
Mono: Assembly Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions[0xa3d4aa0] added to domain Application.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/home/test/Application/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection[0xa3d0f58] -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions[0xa3d4aa0]: 2
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/home/test/Application/System.Runtime.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions[0xa3d4aa0] -> System.Runtime[0xa3d2160]: 3
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Collections/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Collections.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/System.Collections.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5//Facades/System.Collections.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Collections/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Collections.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/System.Collections.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5//Facades/System.Collections.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Collections/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Collections.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/home/test/Application/System.Collections.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/System.Collections.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5//Facades/System.Collections.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Collections/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Collections.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/home/test/Application/System.Collections.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/System.Collections.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5//Facades/System.Collections.exe'.
Mono: The following assembly referenced from /home/test/Application/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll could not be loaded:
     Assembly:   System.Collections    (assemblyref_index=5)
     Version:    4.0.0.0
     Public Key: b03f5f7f11d50a3a
The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment variable, or in the location of the executing assembly (/home/test/Application/).

Mono: Failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection[0xa3d0f58]


Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

I get this output by running my application with the following command

```
MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug MONO_LOG_MASK=asm mono Application.exe
```

What I see is that the assembly loader is trying to load the DependencyInjection, that is also present in the directory where my executable is. Using **dotPeek** I disassembled the **Microsoft.Extension.DependencyInjection.dll** and indeed in it `System.Collection` is present:

[image]

I have looked inside `/usr/lib`(including the `mono` folder) but was unable to find any `System.Collections.dll`, which btw is present on Windows and the application runs just fine there.

I have tried to hunt down all Xamarin packages, which proved to be quite tricky due to the age of the version and the fact that Xamarin made sure it's not easy to find in their repositories. **All projects that are part of the solution target .NET 4.5.1**.

I will try copying the Windows version and hope it works but still, I find it surprising that something that basic is not found.

Comment: Where is the System.Collections.dll located.  In the WOW folder or the System32 folder?  Net 4.5.1 targets 64 bit mode so dlls in the System32 folder are not used.

Comment: On Win10 there are multiple. I'm guessing that the one under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` is used but not sure. If you search inside `C:\` for the dll you get a lot of output. :D

Comment: Did you build for Any CPU and x86?

Comment: Looking at the `sln` file I see a lot of `Any CPU` values for the different project files that are involved so my guess is yes, it's for any CPU. The building takes place through `dotnet` and `cake` commands, which sadly I'm really not familiar with.

Comment: You have multiple projects and changing the settings on the main project will not override the reference project settings.  You would have to look at the build instructions to determine to see if any settings can be changed.  Found interesting article : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt790185.aspx

Comment: The article is mostly addressing smartphone/tablet/PC development. In my case it's an device with bootstrapped Debian Linux on it. Thanks anyway. :)